# WooCommerce Order page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Hey i want to make some changes in woocommerce order page but i couldn't find the right php file to make those changes i changed the html code so i can see that it's possible 
the first screenshot is before the changes 
[image]

As you see i need to move the mouse to see the order note and the last customer note

and this is after the changes 
[image]

i need the name of the file or any other plugin that let me do that

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the hook `manage_posts_custom_column` see codex for more informations. https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column

```
add_action('manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'wpse_306476_order_custom_column');
function wpse_306476_order_custom_column($colname) {
    global $the_order; // Get the order

    if($colname == 'customer_message') // You can also use a switch here
    {
        $message = $the_order->get_customer_note();
        // Do what you have to do here
    }
    elseif($colname == 'order_note') // For order_note
    {
        // Do what you want here
    }
}
```

It's a partial answer, but you'll be able to catch and change what you want in the desired column.